# How to merge columns that both have blank spaces in Google refine

Tags: google-refine

im working with a data base in google refine and I have 2 columns with the information "year". Both columns have values and blank spaces, and where one has a value, the other has a blank space so I want to merge both.

I found this tutorial:
http://kb.refinepro.com/2011/07/merge-2-columns-that-have-both-blank.html

Where the formula: cells["col1"].value + " " + cells["col2"].value
is used, but I dont get what I want, I just get errors and a blank new column.

Comment: Under the video, the tutorial recommend to use facet to exclude column with a blank. Did you try that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try something like if(cells["col1"], cells["col1"].value, "") + if(cells["col2"], cells["col2"].value, "")

It looks like calling value on an empty cell is causing an error